# Как изменить отображение имени выбранного файла в <input type=file>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, input, fileupload

Используются стили пакета Limitless (на основе Bootstrap)

Собственно, имеется пункт выбора файла, и все идет хорошо до тех пор, пока имя файла не очень большое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, когда имя файла очень длинное, элементы начинают немного плыть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какой способ заменить выводимое в браузере имя файла, вырезав, например, середину, чтобы выглядело как на скрине ниже?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набор Limitless обычный код

```html
<input type="file" class="file-styled" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .xls, .xlsx, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .png" name=file[0]/>
```

превращает в конечном виде в:

```
<div class="uploader">
  <input type="file" class="file-styled" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .xls, .xlsx, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .png" name="file[0]/">
  <span class="filename" style="user-select: none;">Файл не выбран</span>
  <span class="action btn bg-grey-300 legitRipple" style="user-select: none;">Выберите файл</span>
</div>
```

Собственно, поменять отображаемое имя файла можно с помощью

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=file]', function(){
    var filename = $(this).next('.filename').html(),
        name = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.')),
        ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.'));

    if (name.length > 20){
        name = name.substr(0, 10) + '...' + name.substr(name.length - 5)
    }
    filename = name + ext;
    $(this).siblings('.filename').html(filename)
});
```

Пример, как выглядит в итоге: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо @Grundy за помощь в поиске решения и @Denis Bubnov за хороший ответ

Answer (score 3):

Да, такую возможность можно реализовать. Если вы указываете фиксированный `width` для `input`, то большинство браузеров должны усечь длинное имя сами. Если не указывать фиксированный `width`, то Вы можете использовать , `text-overflow: ellipsis` но это не будет иметь смысла, пока Вы не используете его с двумя дополнительными свойствами, а также с шириной следующим образом (CSS):

```css
input[type=file] {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<p>Для демонстрации выберите файл с длинным именем</p>
<input type=file>
```

> **`text-overflow`** -определяет параметры видимости текста в блоке, если текст целиком не помещается в заданную область. Возможны два
>   варианта: текст обрезается; текст обрезается и к концу строки
>   добавляется многоточие. [`text-overflow`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-overflow) работает в том случае, если
>   для блока значение свойства `overflow` установлено как `auto`,
>   `scroll` или `hidden`.

- `clip` - текст обрезается по размеру области;
- `ellipsis` - текст обрезается и к концу строки добавляется
  многоточие.

Вот интересная ссылка для изучения: [Обрезаем длинную стро...](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/obrezaem-dlinnuyu-stro)

Comment: я не уверен, что показанное на картинках - это _input[type=file]_

Comment: @Grundy, в заголовке вопроса это написано

Comment: Читать надо не только заголовок.

Comment: @Grundy, я прочел и заголовок и сам вопрос целиком. В `Bootstrap` как-то давно была похожая проблема и решалась так, как я написал. По поводу того, что на картинках - по мне, так там вполне `<input type=file>`, просто прикручены стили, которые немного его видоизменили.

Comment: @Grundy Наверно, никогда не научусь сначала до конца разбираться, а потом спрашивать ><
Да, отображаемое имя в конце концов оборачивается в <span>, с которым, я думаю, особых проблем не будет.

Comment: @Denis Bubnov спасибо за качественный ответ. Надеюсь, он пригодится мне или кому-то еще!

Comment: @RickKross, так что у Вас в результате получилось? Что-то я запутался :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov, _Да, отображаемое имя в конце концов оборачивается в <span>_

Comment: @Grundy, но ведь все же это `<input type=file>` ))) Что подскажете делать в этом случае с ответом? :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov, ничего, если не ошибаюсь ellipsis и со span вполне себе отработает

Comment: @DenisBubnov ответил ниже, как решил. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".file").on("change", function(e){
      var name = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();
      var tmp = "";
      if(name.length > 10)
      {
       tmp =  name.substr(0,5);
       tmp += "..." + name.substr(name.length-6,name.length); 
      }
      else
      {
        tmp = name;
      } 
      $('.spn').text(tmp);
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="file" style="display: none">
<label for="file">Choose </label>&nbsp;<span class="spn"></span>
</form>
```